# Does it make sense to put the array element index as key on Vue v-for element?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am using Vue [`v-for`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html) for iterating over an array, like:

```
<div v-for="item in items">
    {{ item }}
</div>
```

Vue tells me to have a key and recommends me to take a look at the Docs: [`key`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key).

Does that make sense to put the index in the `:key`?

Example:

```
<div v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">
    {{ item }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you Item is an object with an `id` prop then it would be best to use that.

In small scale applications where you are sure your data has no chance of duplication i would use a `name` or `id` prop from the object mixed with the index e.g

```
<div v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="`${item.id}-${index}`">
```

or

```
<div v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="`${item.name}-${index}`">
```

Comment: What advantage does adding the `item` to the key bring here?

Comment: I mean, why is it better than just simply using `index` as key?

Comment: It is fine to use the `index` but with previous experience with an Angular 1.5 project, when manipulating an arrays order it threw a few errors. that is why i go one step further to append an `id` or `name` to the front of the iteration key.

Answer (score 0):

[Using `index` as a key is an anti-pattern](https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318)

> What happens if you push an item to the list or remove something in
>   the middle? If the key is same as before [Vue] assumes that the DOM
>   element represents the same component as before. But that is no longer
>   true.

Comment: This is definitely true when rendering components via `v-for`. But is there any reason to not use the index as the key when just rendering html elements like in OP's example?

Comment: I don't think there's a reason to explicitly use `index` as the `key`. Just ignore the warning. (I don't even get a warning using the above example in a snippet with no key.)

Comment: huh, yeah I see now that I don't get a Vue warning either. My intellisense plugin for vue yells at me though, and I use `index` as `key` to get rid of the ugly red lines.